# C# Linq "Entity with the same key '0' already added." when inserting multiple rows

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, devart, dotconnect

I am trying to insert data in bulk, database is MySQL connection is done using Devart LinqConnect.
Here is a code:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
List<XYData> XYDList = new List<XYData>(); // Data Type
List<xydata> xyToBeInsrted = new List<xydata>(); // Database table

XYDList = XYData.genXYData(12, 1234); // Generates 12 example records 

foreach (XYData oneXY in XYDList)
{
    // Create clear row representation               
    xydata xy_row = new xydata();
    // Assign data from object
    xy_row.id = oneXY.Id;
    xy_row.Batchid = (int)oneXY.BatchId;
    xy_row.Ch = oneXY.Channel;
    xy_row.Value = oneXY.Value;
    xy_row.Pos = (int)oneXY.Position;
    xy_row.Dtm = oneXY.Time;

    // Add to list of rows to be inserted
    xyToBeInsrted.Add(xy_row);

}
db.xydatas.InsertAllOnSubmit<xydata>(xyToBeInsrted);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Last line gives an error "Entity with the same key '0' already added."
When I lower number of items to be generated to 1 then it works. Anything above 1 gives error.

Table has set Auto Increment on record Id field.

Trying to solve that for 2 hours without success.

EDIT:
Data Class:

```
 public class XYData
 {
   [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int BatchId { get; set; }
   public int Channel { get; set; }
   public String Value { get; set; }
   public double Position { get; set; }
   public DateTime Time { get; set; }

   private static Random rand = new Random();

   public XYData(int channel = 0, string val = "")
   {
       Channel = channel;
       Value = val;
       Position = 0;
       Time = DateTime.Now;
   }

   public static List<XYData> genXYData(int howMany, int batchId)
   {
       List<XYData> _allXYData = new List<XYData>();
       for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
       {
           XYData _singleXY = new XYData();
           _singleXY.BatchId = batchId;
           for (int j = 64 * (1 << i); j > 0; j--)
           {
               uint k = (uint)rand.Next(int.MaxValue);
               _singleXY.Value += k.ToString("X8");
           }
           _allXYData.Add(_singleXY); // Add to list
       }
       return _allXYData; // Return list of generated data.
   }
 }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to enter data with the same value in the Primary Key, which must be unique.  Which value is your primary key?  If it is BatchID, BatchID should be a Guid, not an int, to ensure uniqueness of the value.  You may also want to post the contents of genXYData, since it's likely there is a problem with the sample values you are writing.

Comment: Primary key in database is Id, BatchID is a foreign key to other table. Did not created such variable even as I suppose that it is created automatically or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you show the definition of XYData please.

Comment: It is created automatically, in that it is initialized to a default value (0).  You will need to use something like xy_row.ID = Guid.NewGuid(); to assign it (or check for the last value in the database if you insist on sequential ints, but that requires a lot of extra database calls and creates a race condition).  All of your primary keys should be GUIDs unless they are already ensured to be unique (such as a social security number), and even then I think it is better practice to separate the primary key from the actual data.

Comment: So, in the DB, is `BatchId` an `identity` column and auto-generated by the DB? I'm asking because it sounds to me like your C# configuration doesn't know that that field is auto-generated and is therefore assigning it the default value of '0'.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use a GUID just to get this to work.  Have you tried adding Id to the XYData model and marking it up as the key?

Comment: Batch record is inserted as first (to other table) then its ID is used as value for BatchId to create relation.

Comment: @evilbhonda so I have added:
 public class XYData
   {
       **public int Id { get; set; }**
       public int BatchId { get; set; }
How to mark it as key?

Comment: @PawelW See answer below...

Comment: Is it set to auto-incrementing in the Database? I know this sounds odd, but.. I had a similar problem and that was the solution.

Comment: Just to confirm, is XYData and xydata the same class, or are they different?

Comment: Fixed by setting in DataModel that id is auto generated.
XYData and xydata are different as C# is case sensitive. First is an object second is data table representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may be needed on your model definition -

```
[Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/docs/PrimaryKeyMapping.html

Comment: Modified to:
`public class XYData
   {
       [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
       public int Id { get; set; }
`
and
`xydata xy_row = new xydata();
                **xy_row.id = oneXY.Id;**
                xy_row.Batchid = (int)oneXY.BatchId;
` but still the same.

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the Id value, if it's a new row.  The DB should generate that for you, if you've got Identity selected

Comment: Even when I comment out `xy_row.id = oneXY.Id;` it is the same.
It should work but it is not.

Comment: Found the problem. In DataModel genrated by LinqConnect Id field must be also selected as AutoGenerated. Thank you all!